# Create my own error message? But where?

Tags: python, message, calculator

I have created this calculator, however now I want to improve it by creating an error message like "Please only enter numbers". But where would I add this in?

This is my code :

```
def menu():
    print "Welcome to the calculator"
    print "The options are 1) Addition 2)Subtraction 3)Multiplication 4)Division 5)Exit        Calculator"
    return input("Choose your option")

def add(a,b):
    print a+b

def sub(a,b):
    print a-b

def mult(a,b):
    print a*b

def div(a,b):
    print a/b

loop=1
choice=0
while loop==1:
    choice=menu()
    if choice==1:
        add(input("Enter first number"),input("Enter second number"))
    elif choice==2:
         sub(input("Enter first number"),input("Enter second number"))
    elif choice==3:
          mult(input("Enter first number"),input("Enter second number"))
    elif choice==4:
          div(input("Enter first number"),input("Enter second number"))

    elif choice==5:
                loop=0
                exit()
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=raw_input#raw_input) instead of `input`. This gives us a string from the user, which we test to see if its a number. If it isn't a number we ask again.

```
def myInput(message):

    # loop forever / until we have a valid input
    while True:

        # ask user for input
        user_input = raw_input(message)

        # check if its a number
        try:
            result = float(user_input)

            # Valid input, return the result
            return result

        except ValueError:
            # It couldn't be converted to a number, ask again
            print "Please only enter numbers"

            # Repeat the loop / ask again
            continue
```

Then in places where you are currently using `input('some message')` use `myInput('some message')`.

Answer (score 0):

For each `choice` case, you may want to store the input values, and validate them.

```
if choice == 1:
    a = input("Enter first number:")
    while (type(a) != int and type(a) != float):
        a = input("Not a number. Enter first number:")
    b = input("Enter second number:")
    while (type(b) != int and type(b) != float):
        b = input("Not a number. Enter first number:")
    add(a, b)
```

Comment: This makes sense, however I cannot get it to work? I am not sure why though. 
When I test it, it still comes up with the message "q ( or whatever letter I enter" is not defined"
Many thanks

Comment: @user3105095 Did you forget to assign to `q` before you do the type-check? See the second line of the answer: `a = input("Enter first number:")`.

Comment: You should also consider using `isinstance(a, numbers.Number)` (after importing [`numbers`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/numbers.html)) instead of `type(a) != int and type(a) != float`. Using `isinstance` means your code will work with any type of number, including complex numbers :)

Comment: Hi @BenjaminHodgson. Thanks for the extra comments, however I do not quite understand what you mean on the first one. (Sorry!) What should I do to change it?
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

@Christian's already answered your direct question, so I'm going to offer some other simple improvements to your function.

One simple way you could improve this code is to use an explicit `True` or `False` value for your loop control variable. This helps to guard against you making a mistake later and setting `loop` to an invalid value.

You could also extract the 'Enter first number', 'Enter second number' to outside the `if` block to reduce duplication.

You should also try to use indentation more consistently.

```
should_loop = True
while should_loop:
    choice = menu()
    x = input("Enter first number")
    y = input("Enter second number")

    if choice == 1:
        add(x,y)
    elif choice == 2:
        sub(x,y)
    elif choice == 3:
        mult(x,y)
    elif choice == 4:
        div(x,y)
    elif choice == 5:
        should_loop = False
        exit()
```